# Angular universal working on localhost but not in cpanel with passenger

Tags: node.js, angular, cpanel, passenger, angular-universal

I have built the finished sample from [angular universal official page](https://angular.io/guide/universal).

It works perfectly when I use it on localhost in my windows by running:

```
Node dist/server/main.js
```

But when I set it on my cpanel using "Setup Node.js App" tool, It will show me "503 service unavailable" after I start the application and navigate to App URL.

This is my htaccess generated by cpanel:

```
PassengerAppRoot "/home/user_test/blog"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerNodejs "/home/user_test/nodevenv/blog/10/bin/node"
PassengerAppType node
PassengerStartupFile dist/server/main.js
```

My 'stderr.log' is empty in 'blog' directory! But if I change 'main.js' content to the below code, it will work without any problem:

```
const http = require('http')
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 4000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World! NodeJS \n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: Universal listen on port 4000 by default. Where are you redirecting traffic to that port?

Comment: I updated the question with an example. If you change main.js content to some simple HTTP listener to port 4000 it will work successfully.

Comment: Apparently, passenger from cpanel doesn't support angular universal at the time. But I found a very detailed article about starting your angular universal application on cpanel using 'Terminal' or 'SSh Access' tool. [https://www.purcellyoon.com/insights/articles/angular-universal-server-side-rendering-ssr-with-cpanel-whm](https://www.purcellyoon.com/insights/articles/angular-universal-server-side-rendering-ssr-with-cpanel-whm)